# Flink ML - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.ml.math.DenseVector

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, sbt-assembly, flinkml

When submitting a job to my Flink 1.8.1 cluster, it fails with the following exception:

```java
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.ml.math.DenseVector
```

However, the mentioned class seems to be in my jar according to:

```
jar -tf myjar.jar | grep Dense
```

as it shows:

```
...
org/apache/flink/ml/math/DenseVector$$anon$1.class
org/apache/flink/ml/math/DenseVector$.class
org/apache/flink/ml/math/DenseVector.class
```

My Flink dependencies look as follows:

```scala
def flinkDependencies(flinkVersion: String): Seq[ModuleID] = Seq(
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka-0.10" % flinkVersion,
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-ml" % flinkVersion
  )
```

,with Flink Version 1.8.1 and Scala 2.12.8. I create my jar using `sbt assembly`

Any hints?

**Edit**: Same result with Scala 2.11.11 - full stack trace:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed. (JobID: 10cd57f936c7b0fa729ce5159eda4e91)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:268)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:483)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.scala:654)
    at org.hpi.esb.flink.QueryJob.execute(QueryJob.scala:35)
    at org.hpi.esb.flink.JobRunner$.main(JobRunner.scala:10)
    at org.hpi.esb.flink.JobRunner.main(JobRunner.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:529)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:421)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:423)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:813)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:287)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:213)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1050)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$11(CliFrontend.java:1126)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1126)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:146)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:265)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Could not retrieve JobResult.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster.executeJobBlocking(MiniCluster.java:634)
    at org.apache.flink.client.LocalExecutor.executePlan(LocalExecutor.java:223)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.LocalEnvironment.execute(LocalEnvironment.java:91)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:817)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.scala:525)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet.collect(DataSet.scala:739)
    at org.hpi.esb.flink.query.StochasticOutlierSelectionAggregate.getOutliers(StochasticOutlierSelectionQuery.scala:76)
    at org.hpi.esb.flink.query.StochasticOutlierSelectionAggregator.getResult(StochasticOutlierSelectionQuery.scala:41)
    at org.hpi.esb.flink.query.StochasticOutlierSelectionAggregator.getResult(StochasticOutlierSelectionQuery.scala:23)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapAggregatingState.get(HeapAggregatingState.java:92)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator.processElement(WindowOperator.java:399)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.processInput(StreamInputProcessor.java:202)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.run(OneInputStreamTask.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit job.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.Dispatcher.lambda$internalSubmitJob$2(Dispatcher.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:822)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:797)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Could not set up JobManager
    at org.apache.flink.util.function.CheckedSupplier.lambda$unchecked$0(CheckedSupplier.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Could not set up JobManager
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobManagerRunner.<init>(JobManagerRunner.java:152)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DefaultJobManagerRunnerFactory.createJobManagerRunner(DefaultJobManagerRunnerFactory.java:76)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.Dispatcher.lambda$createJobManagerRunner$5(Dispatcher.java:351)
    at org.apache.flink.util.function.CheckedSupplier.lambda$unchecked$0(CheckedSupplier.java:34)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.ml.math.DenseVector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.execution.librarycache.FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders$ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders.java:120)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil$ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(InstantiationUtil.java:78)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1714)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1554)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at java.util.HashSet.readObject(HashSet.java:341)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2176)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:552)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:540)
    at org.apache.flink.util.SerializedValue.deserializeValue(SerializedValue.java:58)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.<init>(JobMaster.java:266)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.createJobMasterService(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.createJobMasterService(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobManagerRunner.<init>(JobManagerRunner.java:146)
    ... 10 more
```